# vstest.console.exe not generating trx file, TestResults empty

Tags: msbuild, xunit, vstest, visual-studio-test-runner

I am trying to run below command on my build server,

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" 
"C:\UnitTest\MyTests.dll"
 /settings:"C:\UnitTest\output.runsettings" 
 /UseVsixExtensions:"true" 
 /InIsolation 
 /Logger:"trx"



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

It generates **TestResults** folder which is empty but doesnt have any **TRX** files.

**Update:** Getting below warning from command line. However dont see that when I run command in my local machine. Am I missing something in my testproject?

> Warning: No test is available in C:\UnitTest\MyTests.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.**

Comment: What does the output say? There should be a line in there like "Result File: ...".

Comment: I am doing it from custom utility which runs this command using process. But let me see if i can capture the command output. I will get back to you.

Comment: I am getting below output from command line:

Comment: Warning: No test is available in C:\UnitTest\MyTests.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Comment: And that could be the reason why you're not getting a TRX file: no tests have been found (and executed).

Comment: Yupp..i think you gave me the hint. Its fixed now..i have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research found that I will need to pass the test adapter for visual studio, which makes the tests discover-able.

```
/TestAdapterPath:"packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.0.99.2
```

Here's the complete command,

```
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" 
/TestAdapterPath:"packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.0.99.2" "C:\UnitTest\MyTests.dll"
 /settings:"C:\UnitTest\output.runsettings" 
 /UseVsixExtensions:"true" 
 /InIsolation 
 /Logger:"trx"
```

There is a nuget package available for xunit visual studio test adapter "**xunit.runner.visualstudio.0.99.2**"

Comment: I had same problem and this fixed my issue. Thanks!